# Knowage Bi start -MariaDb

Tags: database, mariadb, innodb, knowage

When i want to Start Knowage CE i get the following error in CMD (Windows 10 Os):

```
 2018-07-28 22:23:31 15040 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for
 `knowage_ce`.`sbi_whatif_workflow` because it could not be opened. 
 2018-07-28 22:23:31 15040 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error
 number 3 in a file operation.  2018-07-28 22:23:31 15040 [ERROR]
 InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified. 
 2018-07-28 22:23:31 15040 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing
 InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB
 does not create them. 2018-07-28 22:23:31 15040 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot
 open datafile for read-only: '.\knowage_ce\sbi_ws_event.ibd' OS error:
 203  2018-07-28 22:23:31 15040 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid
 tablespace file for `knowage_ce/sbi_ws_event`. Please refer to
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
```

How can I resolve this issue?

And i can't Connect to Knowage CE at:
http://localhost:MyDomaineName:8080/Name

Comment: Hello Yoshi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It would be helpful if you read [tour] and [ask] and then used [edit] to improve your question based on that guidance.  For example part of the text of your error says "_Operating system error number 3_" but we don't know what Operating System you are using so it is difficult to interpret error number 3.  We could guess of course but that may waste everyone's time.  Another part of the error text says "_If you are installing
 InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself_".  Are you sure you have created necessary directories correctly?

Comment: My Os Windows 10 and for the directories problem i really dont understand the message , i have a folder called MariaDB in Knowage directorie and i dont get what the error is ?(what is the  difference betwwen  InnoDB and MariaDB)

Comment: The Windows error code `203` is **ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND**: _The system could not find the environment option that was entered_.  [see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).  Did you set up the `JDK` and the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable as per [Knowage CE: How To Install JDK](https://www.knowage-suite.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/How-to-InstallConfigure-JDK-WIN.pdf)?  The [CE Download page](https://www.knowage-suite.com/site/ce-download/) mentions **environment prerequisites** but has a broken link.

Comment: I faced lots of errors when first tried to use Embedded MariaDB, at last I installed a MySQL Server 5.X separately, and reinstalled the KNOWAGE with MySQL option. and it worked. But apart from this question, KNOWAGE has still lots of bugs, and it's just at the beginning of its journey.